# How to (repeatedly) create and shut down multiple instances of python twisted factory / reactor?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

Firstly, my apologies for the title to this thread - it probably could be worded better, but I'm not sure I know how! Anyway...

I have the following methods to start, and stop my SMTP Server respectively:

```
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def startServer(configName = 'default'):
    try:
        svrCfg = getServerConfig(configName)
        startLogger (svrCfg.find('logfile').text)
        portal = Portal(SimpleRealm())
        checker = InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
        checker.addUser("guest", "password")
        portal.registerChecker(checker)
        serverPort = int(svrCfg.find('port').text)
        reactor.listenTCP(serverPort, ConsoleSMTPFactory((portal, svrCfg)))
        Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()
        # reactor.run()
    except twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError, e:
        errString = "Cannot start server, port " + svrCfg.find('port').text + " is busy"
        log.msg (errString, logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)
    except:
        log.msg ("Unknown error", logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def stopServer():
    reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The long term plan is that `startServer` and `stopServer` will be `RobotFramework` keywords. For now though, it is of course sufficient to go to the python command line, import the source module `(mailserver.py`) and just do "`mailserver.startServer()`" or "`mailserver.stopServer()"` etc. This is fine for starting the server first time, and stopping it.

However we want to be able to start / stop multiple, concurrent mailservers, listening on different ports - so for example, `mailserver.startServer("p25")` `mailserver.startServer("p26")`, `mailserver.stopServer("p25")` would start 2 instances, then shut the first one down.

Even with my existing code, just restarting the "default" listener fails with a ReactorNotRestartable error... And of course, starting the "default" listener, then starting a "p26" listener results in "ReactorAlreadyRunning" error.

Can anyone offer advice on how to get around these errors? Firstly, how to get multiple listeners, and secondly, how to specify which one to shut down as part of "stopServer"?

(incidentally, using Thread so as to allow startServer to exit for the next RobotFramework keyword to execute...)

Many thanks

EDIT - FOLLOWING @JeanPaul-Calderone 's answer... I've managed to create the following:

So I've tweaked my code to support adding / removing listeners, as below:

```
def addListener(configName = 'default'):
    try:
        svrCfg = getServerConfig(configName)
        startLogger (svrCfg.find('logfile').text)
        portal = Portal(SimpleRealm())
        checker = InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
        checker.addUser("guest", "password")
        portal.registerChecker(checker)
        serverPort = int(svrCfg.find('port').text)
        listenerPort = reactor.listenTCP(serverPort, ConsoleSMTPFactory((portal, svrCfg)))
        runningListeners[configName] = listenerPort
        print runningListeners
    except twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError, e:
        errString = "Cannot start server, port " + svrCfg.find('port').text + " is busy"
        log.msg (errString, logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)
    except:
        log.msg ("Unknown error", logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def stopListener(configName = 'default'):
    listenerPort = runningListeners[configName]
    print listenerPort
    listenerPort.stopListening()
    listenerPort.connectionLost("Closing listener as requested")
    del runningListeners[configName]


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()
runningListeners={}
```

I can certainly now add and remove multiple listeners... However, when I tried to (for debug purposes) Ctrl-D from my python command line session, it hung - I had to Ctrl-Z, and kill the job.

So I realised the reactor had been left running, so I added:

```
def stopReactor():
    reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)
```

But now when I Ctrl-D from the Python session:

```
    Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 832, in <lambda>
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: callable(*args, **kw))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1115, in connectionLost
    self._closeSocket(True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 123, in _closeSocket
    skt = self.socket
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Port' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

Can anyone advise what I am now getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only start the Twisted reactor once.  If you have multiple tasks you want to accomplish, you need to start the reactor before the first one and only stop it after the last one.  You can't start and stop it around each task.

You may find [crochet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet) helpful in managing the reactor for this usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks as ever @Jean-PaulCalderone ... I sort of inferred (accurately?!) from your comment that once the reactor was running, I could add / remove more listeners, which I've tried... this seems to work, but not quite 100% - I've edited the question to include my revised code above....

Comment: Indeed, just about all Twisted APIs work as well (or better!) after the reactor has been started.  As you discovered (I think) the exception about the `socket` attribute was due to calling `connectionLost` instead of `stopListening`.

Answer (score 0):

Scrap that latest question....

Final working solution appears to be below!

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def addListener(configName = 'default'):
    try:
        svrCfg = getServerConfig(configName)
        startLogger (svrCfg.find('logfile').text)
        portal = Portal(SimpleRealm())
        checker = InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
        checker.addUser("guest", "password")
        portal.registerChecker(checker)
        serverPort = int(svrCfg.find('port').text)
        listenerPort = reactor.listenTCP(serverPort, ConsoleSMTPFactory((portal, svrCfg)))
        runningListeners[configName] = listenerPort
        print runningListeners
    except twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError, e:
        errString = "Cannot start server, port " + svrCfg.find('port').text + " is busy"
        log.msg (errString, logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)
    except:
        log.msg ("Unknown error", logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)


def startServer(configName = 'default'):
    try:
        svrCfg = getServerConfig(configName)
        startLogger (svrCfg.find('logfile').text)
        portal = Portal(SimpleRealm())
        checker = InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
        checker.addUser("guest", "password")
        portal.registerChecker(checker)
        serverPort = int(svrCfg.find('port').text)
        reactor.listenTCP(serverPort, ConsoleSMTPFactory((portal, svrCfg)))
        Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()
    except twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError, e:
        errString = "Cannot start server, port " + svrCfg.find('port').text + " is busy"
        log.msg (errString, logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)
    except:
        log.msg ("Unknown error", logLevel=logging.CRITICAL)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def stopListener(configName = 'default'):
    listenerPort = runningListeners[configName]
    print listenerPort
    blockingCallFromThread(reactor, listenerPort.stopListening)
    del runningListeners[configName]

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

def stopReactor():
    reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()
runningListeners={}
```